# Centos 5 missing rtcwake

Tags: centos5

I can't seem to find the rtcwake command in my Centos 5 installation.  Searching Google hasn't really turned up any results, though I thought it should be part of the util-linux package and doesn't seem to be.

Furthermore, running:

```
yum provides *bin/rtcwake
```

returns no matches.

Comment: Did you try installing epel and remi repo ? Maybe you can find this app in those repos

Comment: Epel is installed.  I'm looking at Remi now.

Comment: Nope, not in remi either.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search through [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=rtcwake&submit=Search%20...&system=&arch=) shows that the `/sbin/rtcwake` is available via the util-linux (Fedora) or util-linux-ng (CentOS 6.x) packages. This package isn't immediately available for CentOS 5. You may be able to get a Fedora package to install or compile from source rpm.

It sounds like you're used to using the command. Are you coming from a different distribution that has it?

Comment: I want to put my server to sleep at a certain time at night and wake it up at a certain time in the morning.  All the online resources I've seen use rtcwake to do this, and it seems most other distros have it.  I even tried copying the rtcwake from another distro executable but it doesn't work with the way Centos 5's /sys/ filesystem is laid out.  Maybe I should post a question asking for alternative ways of doing this.

Comment: Ah, there may be an issue with the capabilities of the old CentOS 5 2.6.18 kernel series.

Comment: That's the feeling I was getting.  In fact I have another server that's running Centos 6 (which has rtcwake) but it couldn't successfully put the computer sleep.  Evidently a lot of non-laptop boards struggle with this according to what I've been reading so I'll probably just shut the server down by cron and power it on manually in the morning.